# perl Convert::ASN1 decoding not working

Tags: perl, asn.1, ocsp

I am trying to decode asn.1 OCSP request with perl Convert::ASN1
The hex dump I get is as follows:

```
30773075304E304C304A300906052B0E03021A050004146283D6C38BF724E2EE10A7D2829A4F906E48F3F2041423490CF9B7D39B1BD93A60A2A67877894782E96F021100B1C544D7AFA4039D4F482BDDEE975E38A2233021301F06092B060105050730010204120410ABE72957E85AE50E8B9628DB495BD5D5
```

I used an online tool to verifiy that it is a valid asn.1 encoded and the structure is as follows

```
SEQUENCE {
   SEQUENCE {
      SEQUENCE {
         SEQUENCE {
            SEQUENCE {
               SEQUENCE {
                  OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.3.14.3.2.26 (id_sha1)
                  NULL 
               }
               OCTETSTRING 6283D6C38BF724E2EE10A7D2829A4F906E48F3F2
               OCTETSTRING 23490CF9B7D39B1BD93A60A2A67877894782E96F
               INTEGER 0x00B1C544D7AFA4039D4F482BDDEE975E38
            }
         }
      }
      [2] {
         SEQUENCE {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1.2
               OCTETSTRING 0410ABE72957E85AE50E8B9628DB495BD5D5
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I pack the hex up to decode

```
my $data = "30773075304E304C304A300906052B0E03021A050004146283D6C38BF724E2EE10A7D2829A4F906E48F3F2041423490CF9B7D39B1BD93A60A2A67877894782E96F021100B1C544D7AFA4039D4F482BDDEE975E38A2233021301F06092B060105050730010204120410ABE72957E85AE50E8B9628DB495BD5D5";
my $asn1Val=pack("H*",$data);
```

I created my asn1.1 schema from this

```
my  $asn = Convert::ASN1->new;
$asn->prepare( q<
   OCSPRequest     ::=     SEQUENCE {
       tbsRequest                  TBSRequest,
       optionalSignature   [0]     EXPLICIT Signature OPTIONAL
   }

   TBSRequest      ::=     SEQUENCE {
       version             [0]     EXPLICIT Version OPTIONAL,   -- DEFAULT v1
--       requestorName       [1]     EXPLICIT GeneralName OPTIONAL,
       requestList                 SEQUENCE OF Request,
       requestExtensions   [2]     EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
   }

   Request         ::=     SEQUENCE {
       reqCert                     CertID,
       singleRequestExtensions     [0] EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
   }

   AlgorithmIdentifier  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        algorithm           OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
        parameters          ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL
   }

   CertID          ::=     SEQUENCE {
       hashAlgorithm        AlgorithmIdentifier,
       issuerNameHash       OCTET STRING, -- Hash of issuer's DN
       issuerKeyHash        OCTET STRING, -- Hash of issuer's public key
       serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber
   }

   CertificateSerialNumber  ::=  INTEGER

   Extension  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        extnID      OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
        critical    BOOLEAN OPTIONAL, -- DEFAULT FALSE,
        extnValue   OCTET STRING
                    -- contains the DER encoding of an ASN.1 value
                    -- corresponding to the extension type identified
                    -- by extnID
        }

   Extensions  ::=  SEQUENCE OF Extension

   Signature       ::=     SEQUENCE {
       signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
       signature            BIT STRING
--,       certs             [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE OF Certificate OPTIONAL
   }

   Version     ::=  INTEGER  -- {  v1(0) }

>)
```

When I try to deocode the above it works some times and fails somes time.

```
asn_dump($data); # This works fine
my $decoded=$asn->decode($data) or print $asn->error();
print Dumper ($decoded);
```

I think the schema is correct but the decoding is failing 
I have not been able to find many examples online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The significant point you make here is you say "it works some times and fails some times".  To me, that's a clue that you did not use find() to tell Convert::ASN1 where to start in your definition.

You must use find() if there's more than one macro (one typedef) in the ASN.1 that you prepare.  Then use the resulting object from the find() to do your decode().  Remember, too, to always check the return status from find() and decode(); if undef then the error will be in ->error() for the object you used.

```
my $asn = new Convert::ASN1;
my $ok = $asn->prepare( q< ...your asn.1 definition here... >);
die "*** Could not prepare definition: ".$asn->error()
  if !$ok;
my $top = $asn->find("OCSPRequest");
die "*** Could not find top of structure: ".$asn->error()
  if !$top;
my $result = $top->decode($your_pdu);   # Use $top, NOT $asn !
die "*** Could not decode PDU: ".$top->error()
  if !$result;
```

This is a bit of a guess as your question doesn't give me enough context, but I hope it helps.

Comment: This was the solution to the issue I was having.